# basic inequality using quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

in multiplication and division we change the direction of the inequality symbol. For example: $6>3 \Longrightarrow 6(-2) < 3(-2), \text{ and } 10 > 3 = > \frac{10}{-2} < \frac{3}{(-2)}$.

How does the inequality symbol change direction when
$x^2+x-2>0$ ?

The above can be written as: $( x-(-2)\, ) \cdot (x-1) > 0 \Longleftrightarrow ( x+2\, ) \cdot (x-1) > 0$. I am expecting to see:

$x>1$ or $x+2>0 \Longrightarrow x>-2$, but it is wrong.It should be $x<-2$. What am i forgetting to do right to the inequality x>-2? What math property am i missing?

Comment: i fixed that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $( x+2\, ) \cdot (x-1) > 0$ is a *product*, you need [$x>1$ *and* $x>-2$] (i.e. $x>1$) OR  [$x<1$ *and* $x<-2$] (i.e. $x< -2$)